# Invalid signature posted to coinbase pro API via python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to connect to [coinbase](https://www.coinbase.com/) pro API through python and I think I've done everything correctly however I keep getting a  401 response with invalid signature.

can someone please look through my code and ensure it is doing what its supposed to

```py
    import json, hmac, hashlib, time, requests, base64
    from requests.auth import AuthBase
    
    def authentication(api_key, secret_key, passphrase):
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = '{}{}{}'.format(timestamp, 'GET', 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com/accounts')
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(secret_key)
        encoded_message = message.encode()
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, encoded_message, hashlib.sha256).digest()
        signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature)
      
               
        headers = {
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': passphrase,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        return headers
    
    api_url = 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com/'
    auth = authentication('kjdvgfskjidfahvgkjia', 'kshfhg/hsdkjdsjdkjkldkdskighsokjf/jgjgjgjg==', 'helllooooo')
    
    r = requests.get(api_url + 'accounts', headers=auth)
    print(r)
    print(r.text)
```

as per the website API documentation it states that -

All REST requests must contain the following headers:

```
    CB-ACCESS-KEY The api key as a string.   
    CB-ACCESS-SIGN The base64-encoded signature (see Signing a Message).
    CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP A timestamp for your request.
    CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE The passphrase you specified when creating the
    API key. All request bodies should have content type
    application/json and be valid JSON.
```

The CB-ACCESS-SIGN header is generated by creating a sha256 HMAC using the base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string timestamp + method + requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation) and base64-encode the output. The timestamp value is the same as the CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP header.

The body is the request body string or omitted if there is no request body (typically for GET requests).

```
The method should be UPPER CASE.
```

I've already had a complete mare getting to this stage.
the two print statements at the end come back with

```
    <Response [401]>
    {"message":"invalid signature"}
    [Finished in 0.4s]
```

everything looks okay to me however it clearly isn't